# Action bar does not dissappear

Tags: android, android-layout

I have just begun to learn Android coding and I want to disable the default action bar that is at the upper rim of my main activity and replace it by a toolbar that is customizable. I looked at this webpage and followed the instructions: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Unfortunately the actionbar does not dissappear. While the toolbar is shown, the actionbar still remains at the upper rim of the activity layout.

I inserted this code both in the manifest and in the layout file:

application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

If I insert it in the layout file, the newly created toolbar becomes transparent, which is not what I want. I want to default action bar to disappear. 
If I insert it in the Manifest, nothing happens

**Here is a part of the xml code of the layout file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="331dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.018"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I would be very happy, if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `styles.xml` and use a `NoActionBar` theme which extends from `AppCompat`. As for the white space between the toolbar and the status bar, you may fix it by removing the margin_top property of the toolbar. It is also advisable to use `?attr/actionBarSize` for the height of toolbars for compatibility among different screen sizes. Toolbars should also match their parent's width with no margins between them. I've updated your code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.018"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rafsanjani for you help. What does the attribute "?attr/actionBarSize" do? I used in my example dp for the sizing. I thought that this is device independent.

Answer (score 3):

In your `styles.xml` file :

**Change**:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

**to**

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

Now you use your toolbar any how you want it

Hope this works...Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks DaveAAA for your answer. It helped me:-)
I am wondering why this is not mentioned on the developers website

Comment: There is still a small empty space between the toolbar and the status information bar of the phone. How can I get rid of that? I want the new toolbar to begin immediately after the status information bar of the phone. Currently there is a white empty space underneath it